# Using "export default" to export all functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

How can I export all of the functions in a JS file using `export default` into my NPM package? (the idea is for users to be able to import the framework using `import Mathium from 'mathiumjs'` and not have to import every function manually.

Comment: The standard practice for importing everything is `import * as Mathium from 'mathiumjs'`, is there a reason that does not work for you?

Comment: @JakeHolzinger yeah, but users can't do it if I don't export all of the functions as "Mathium". The way they import it doesn't matter to me, just an example

Comment: You could also `export default` an object that has different functions as properties, such that users would then type `Mathium.someFunc()`

Comment: @tmdesigned can you give me an example on how to do that?

Comment: @FilippoFonseca that's incorrect, `Mathium` is just an alias, you don't have to name every function with `Mathium`. You could write `import * as foo from 'mathiumjs'`, it's the same thing.

Comment: @JakeHolzinger `import * as SomeName` is one way to do it, but it's not nearly the most common method and not super friendly for end users. Only a few packages I use use that pattern, like Node's `fs`.

Comment: @JakeHolzinger gotcha

Comment: @Silbox it's very common. It's how tree shaking works. If you use the default export to expose everything you don't get tthe benefits of tree shaking. Not that it's indicated in the OP that they would want to use tree shaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as simple as doing something like this at the top level of your framework.

**Index.js**

```js
import * as someName from './subIndex';
export default someName
```

**subIndex.js**

```js
export * from './someFile';
export * from './someOtherFile';
```

Comment: Could you show me how I would branch out the functions exactly? https://github.com/filippo-fonseca/mathiumjs

Comment: Remove all the lines like `module.exports.radToDeg = radToDeg;` and instead add the word `export` before the function declarations. So `export function radToDeg`. What `export * from './someFile'` does is takes all the named exports from a file and exports them all. Then when you `import * as someName` you grab every named import and assign them all to the variable `someName`.

Comment: Thx! :) Appreciate that!

Comment: Happy to help! Don't forget to upvote and accept the answer if this solves your issue!

Comment: You'll only need that if you have multiple files you're exporting functions from. Since all your functions are in your `index.js` it's sufficient to just have `export function radToDeg`. If you had another file that also contained functions, you would use `export * from './someFile'` for each one, so that they could all then be imported together. PS, I'm a bit confused by [this line](https://github.com/mathium-framework/mathiumjs/blob/master/src/index.js#L2), seems like the file it's referencing doesn't exist.